# How to populate React UI Form elements using an Elasticsearch Query String?

Tags: reactjs, .net, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an application that can create and store reports that use a set of filters.

Basically, there is a set of documents stored on a server (Elasticsearch).

I want to have the capability for users to retrieve documents from this server and apply a set of filters on them. The user should be able to choose which columns they want to display and the filters they need for their purposes. The filters and column data themselves will be stored as a Report object in some other database (Mongo).

If a user wants to view that same set of filters and columns, they can retrieve the stored Report from Mongo.

Is this the best way to implement this behavior?

Currently, I have created a .NET API that will retrieve Elasticsearch Query DSLs in a POST request and send back all the documents that match the query. I have also created Mongo API routes to store and retrieve a Report object, using the Query DSL as a string field and the required columns as a list.

The idea is that when a user accesses a created report, they will retrieve the Report object from Mongo. Then, the webpage will automatically send the stored Query DSL to the Elastic endpoint and use the returned data to create the document view along with the fields the user requires.

The part that confuses me is how to build the UI elements. I know I have to build the Elasticsearch Query DSL from various form elements, but the inverse is what confuses me. How do I populate the UI form elements when I am opening a report that already has filters applied?